# How to Fixed MBProgressHUD size

Tags: objective-c, mbprogresshud

I init a hud and set frame CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40) to show a letter, but the width of letter is different, the size of hud is changed as the letters change. How can I fixed the size of hud? Thanks for every help.

```
MBProgressHUD * hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
[self.view addSubview:hud];
hud.label.text = text;//test = @"A" or @"B" or @"C"...etc
[hud showAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Using `initWithFrame:` is not the right way to create a `MBProgressHUD`. You should try to use `HUDForView:` or `showHUDAddedTo:animated:` instead. If you want to customize hud size, use `minSize` property. For example, `hud.minSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40)`. You can take a look at https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD#usage

Comment: Trungduc, your answer is correct. Thank you.